# How to save the recorded audio file from discord

Tags: discord, save, pycord

I am developing a discord bot for recording, I am currently trying to save the recording locally and concatinate the recordings together. Please can someone advise how to save the audio files before sending them to the channel.

```
class Sinks(Enum):
    wav = discord.sinks.WaveSink()


async def finished_callback(sinks, channel: discord.TextChannel, *args,):
    today = date.today()
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
    recorded_users = [f"<@{channel}>" for channel, audio in sinks.audio_data.items()]
    
    await sinks.vc.disconnect()
    
    **files = {
        discord.File(audio.file, f"{now}.{sinks.encoding}")
        for channel, audio in sinks.audio_data.items()
        
    }
    await channel.send(f"Finished! Recorded audio for :  {', '.join(recorded_users)}.", files=files)**
   
    
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    """
    Record your voice!
    """
    voice = ctx.author.voice
    if not voice:
        return await ctx.send("You're not in a vc right now")

    vc = await voice.channel.connect()
    connections.update({ctx.guild.id: vc})


    vc.start_recording(
        discord.sinks.WaveSink(),
        finished_callback,
        ctx.channel,
    )
    await ctx.send("The recording has started!")
    
    

@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    """Stop recording."""
    if ctx.guild.id in connections:
        vc = connections[ctx.guild.id]
        vc.stop_recording()
        del connections[ctx.guild.id]
##        await ctx.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not recording in this guild.")

    
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Pycord or just the Rapptz discord fork that adds audio recording? I ran into a similar question and had to spend some time digging into the code for discord.File and the sinks in order to write locally to the disk.

Note that the name audio.file is a little deceptive; it's not actually a filename but rather an _io.BytesIO object. This can, however, be written to a file on the disk by adding the following after "await sinks.vc.disconnect()" in finished_callback:

```
for user_id, audio in sinks.audio_data.items():
    with open("output.wav", "wb") as f:
        f.write(audio.file.getbuffer())
```

That will write the BytesIO object output to the disk with the filename specified. Make sure the file suffix matches your audio encoding (eg, mp3, wav, ogg) depending on what you selected for your recording sink. I've tested and this works for me to produce local files from discord recordings.

Comment: Is there a way to stop_recording() when the the user STOPS speaking?